# Upper bound of a chain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm working on a problem in Abstract Algebra by Dummit&Foote.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and suppose that every prime ideal in $R$ is principal. (a) Assume that the set of ideals of $R$ that are not principal is nonempty and prove that this set has a maximal element under inclusion [Use Zorn's Lemma].

My plan:

1. Let the set of ideals that are not principal be $S$, by assumption $S\neq \emptyset$
2. Under $\subseteq$, $S$ is a poset.
3. Let $A\subseteq S$ be a chain. We'll prove that $A$ has an upper bound in $S$.
4. Apply Zorn's Lemma

However, I don't know how to prove that the existence of an upper bound. I tried to prove it by induction on $|A|$, but it only works for finite cardinality. What if $A$ is infinite? I've also tried to set the upper bound as the sum of all ideals in $A$. But it is not necessarily non-principal.

Comment: Always take the union of the ideals in the chain to get an upper bound. You just need to prove this union is indeed not principal.

Comment: @Mark But the union of ideals is not necessarily an ideal...?

Comment: It is when they're nested, as is the case in a chain of ideals.  If you don't already know that, you can easily prove it directly from the definition of an ideal.

Comment: @Irene If that's a union of a chain then it is. For example, why is it closed under addition? Since this is a chain, given two elements $x,y$ there is some ideal in the union which contains both elements. If so, their sum also belongs to the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq\dots$ be a chain of ideals which are not principal. To get an upper bound of this chain, i.e. an ideal $I\supseteq I_i$ for all $i$, take $I:=\bigcup_iI_i$ as suggested in the comments.

First you have to prove that $I$ is actually an ideal. If $x,y\in I$, there must be $i_0,i_1$ such that $x\in I_{i_0}$ and $y\in I_{i_1}$; suppose wlog that $i_1\ge i_0$. So $x,y\in I_{i_1}$, and $x+y\in I_{i_1}\subseteq I$. Similarly, $rx\in I_{i_0}\subseteq I$ for all $r\in R$.

Now for this problem specifically, you must prove that the union of nested non-principal ideals is not principal. Suppose that $I=(x)$. Then $x\in I_{i_0}$ implies that $I=(x)\subseteq I_{i_0}$, so $I= I_{i_0}$, contradicting the hypothesis that $I_{i_0}$ is not principal.